# How do I remove whitespace at the beginning of my string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, whitespace

Let's say I have following string:
`string test = " False";`

I can't loop the characters of the string because I need to do this for 1744 strings, then it would be a lot of work.

Do you know if there is a method from Microsoft that I can use to delete this whitespace?

Like this: `string test2 = test.DeleteFirstWhitespace();`

Thanks

Comment: which language? for java it is trim()

Comment: I think the java tag is a mistake. Unless the OP things MS make java.

Comment: Do you need Java or C# solution? If it is Java please change `string` to `String`. Otherwise, remove `java` tag.

Comment: *I can't loop the characters of the string because I need to do this for 1744 strings*: `TrimStart` does this same thing: it iterates through string's characters until there is a non-whitespace character found. Why do you think there should be a difference if you have 1700 strings, or even 20 million?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use [`TrimStart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimstart.aspx) in C#:

```
string test2 = test.TrimStart()
```

Comment: +1 for the more specialized solution; if the user doesn't care about trailing whitespace, or actually needs same, this is the ticket.

Answer (score 2):

As everyone else has pointed out, there is a trim function.  Make sure to remember that a string is immutable, so when you call test.Trim(), it will not modify the test variable, it will return a new string:

```
string trimmed = test.Trim();
// or
string trimmed = test.TrimStart();
```

Answer (score 1):

how about using the `trim()` function:

```
string test = test.trim();
```

Answer (score 1):

`test.trim();`
This method removes whitespaces from beginning and ending of the string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

- [String.Trim()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim.aspx) to remove all leading and trailing white-space characters
- [String.TrimStart()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimstart.aspx) to remove only leading white-space characters
- [String.TrimEnd()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend.aspx) to remove only trailing white-space characters

All these have additional overloads which let you specify an array of custom characters also to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking of `Java`: `String.trim()`. Here is the link to the API documentation:
[`String.trim()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

**In java:**

Use [`trim()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) to remove the whitespaces around a String:

```
String test2 = test.trim();
```

> Returns a copy of the string, with leading and trailing whitespace omitted.

Answer (score 0):

I can also use the method `TrimStart()`

like this:

`string test2 = test.TrimStart(' ');`