# Remove whitespace around string Java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

### Summary

I am developing a programming language in Java (using Eclipse). For my compiler, I split the text the user inputs in using the character ";", then converts the list to an ArrayList. It then goes through each line in the ArrayList, and checks what it is doing.

### The Problem?

When it breaks it down into multiple lines, there is a "\n" at the beginning of the line because each line of code is on it's own line.

I am doing somethings with calling functions using variables, for example,

```
container.callFunction();
```

So I have to figure out is "container" is a variable. I have an ArrayList of all the variables created while running the code. So in the ArrayList containing variables, called "variables", is the string "container". But when my compiler breaks the lines down, it ends up with "\ncontainer", then I use the ArrayList.contains() method to confirm the item is a variable. But in variables, there is "container", but no "\ncontainer".

I know a solution to this, but I just don't exactly know how to do it. I could remove the "\n" from the beginning of the variables array. Does any one know how to do that, or have a better solution to this?

Comment: How are you splitting it

Comment: Why not simply `.trim()` the String before searching for a token? That would remove the leading `\n`

Comment: @user7 using the `.split()` method.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Wow. I never thought of that. I am so dumb.

Comment: Then put in white space markers as part of your split regex

Comment: This is a duplicate...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove whitespace at the beginning of my string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8883152/how-do-i-remove-whitespace-at-the-beginning-of-my-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call [.trim(..)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim--) on the variable that contains the word “\ncontainer” before checking if it’s in your “variables” list.